# Duplicando o valor retornado ao executar o onDataCahage no FIREBASE, podem me ajudar?

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, nosql

Desejo recuperar o valor de uma movimentação no Firebase e guardar esse valor sempre que o campo `flag` for `"noDebitado"` e posteriormente, a cada interação do loop `for`, quero definir um novo valor para `flag` dentro do Firebase para `"debitado"`.

Fazendo dessa seguinte forma eu consigo obter o valor de cada movimentação:

```
public void pegarValorMov(){
    String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    String idUsuario = Base64Custon.codificarBase64(emailUsuario);
    movimentacaoRef = firebaseRef.child("movimentacao").child( idUsuario).child( mesAnoSelecionado );

    valueEventListenerMov = movimentacaoRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dados : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Movimentacao movimentacao = dados.getValue(Movimentacao.class);

                //retornando o nó principal de cada movimentacao
                key = dados.getKey();

                if (movimentacao.getFlag().equals("noDebitado")) {
                    //recupera o valor da movimentaçao
                    valorReceita = movimentacao.getValor();

                    //exibe o valor da movimentacao atual
                    Log.i("VALOR", "Valor Receita " + valorReceita );

                    //soma o valor da movimentação a cada interaçao
                    vReceita = vReceita + valorReceita;

                }

            }//fim do for

            //exibe o valor total das movimentacoes encontradas para futuros calculos
            Log.i("VALOR", "Valor Receita total " + vReceita );

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desejo alterar o valor da `flag` sempre que ela for igual a `"noDebitado"`, tentei fazer isso acrescentando a seguinte linha de código dentro do bloco `if`.

```
            if (movimentacao.getFlag().equals("noDebitado")) {
                //recupera o valor da movimentaçao
                valorReceita = movimentacao.getValor();

                //exibe o valor da movimentacao atual
                Log.i("VALOR", "Valor Receita " + valorReceita );

                //soma o valor da movimentação a cada interaçao
                vReceita = vReceita + valorReceita;

                //trecho que alterar o valor da flag no firebase
                movimentacaoRef.child(key).child("flag").setValue("debitado");

            }
```

Funcionou, o valor da `flag` no Firebase foi alterado, porém emite um resultado um pouco estranho (imagem abaixo), dessa forma o valor de cada movimentação se repetisse, como se o loop `for` rodasse mais vezes que a quantidade de itens existentes no Firebase.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... encontrei alguns assuntos sobre o `onDataChange` executar mais de uma vez quando um dado é alterado no Firebase, mas ficou um pouco confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencionei, o `onDataChange` realiza mais "chamadas" quando ha alteração de dados, por isso ele parece "repetir" os valores. Simplesmente consultando a documentação encontrei a solução acrescentando apenas uma única linha:

```
// Remove listener
ref.removeEventListener(listener);
```

Utiliza-se isso para desconectar callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem o código e a sua intenção.
Mas tem alguns detalhes que precisa saber sobre o Realtime Database.
Note que você inicialmente está criando um listener para "movimentacaoRef" logo qualquer dado modificado irá adcionar o trigger onDataChange e executando sua função.
Notei que dentro do onDataChange você modifica o propria referencia do banco de dados. Cuidado com isso pois pode criar um loop infinito no RTDB (na verdade está criando).

A maneira mais propícia e segura de se fazer isto seria fazer uma Transaction (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=pt-br#save_data_as_transactions)
sendo assim pode executar de forma atomica várias atualizações.

outra opção é em vez de criar um listener, ler o banco de dados somente uma vez utilizando o get().addOnCompleteListener. Sendo assim você previne de loops indesejados.

uma regra para fazer banco de dados e seu app funcionar melhor e lembrar que uma vez que você possui um listener evitar fazer várias gravações separadas seja paralelas ou consecutivas. tente agrupar tudo de preferencia em uma Transaction.

Por fim, as vezes é melhor mesmo nem executar no app do cliente certos de tipos de codigos que fazem calculos no banco de dados. nessas situação prefere-se usar o backend. Recomendo até o Firebase functions.

Comment: Obrigado por contribuir Paulo, sua ajudo me auxiliou a encontrar a solução.
Realmente quando a "flag" era alterada o onDataChange era acionado novamente, assim gerando "loop" (callback). E realmente alterar o valor da "flag" diretamente 
dessa forma: 
movimentacaoRef.child(key).child("flag").setValue("debitado"); 
não é muito adequado, então criei um metodo de update dentro da classe para ser acionado quando desejado.

 Vlw, abraço.